# dataview rowfilter not working as expected

Tags: c#, dataview, rowfilter

Please go easy on me with this, i'm totally self taught with C# and its something I only really get a chance to play with in my spare time!

I have a datatable which contains one column of boolean type. I am binding this table to a datagridview and using the boolean type to display a column of empty checkboxes, a user can then check the box next to any number of rows. I also have a "show checked rows" checkbox on the form which, when checked, filters the datagridview to only show checked rows, the code looks like this:

filling the datagrid:

```
public void fillDatagridView()
{
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("Print", typeof(bool));
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("Contact ID", typeof(string));
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("Membership Number", typeof(int));
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("Current Application Type", typeof(string));
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("Email Address", typeof(string));
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("Membership Type", typeof(string));
    dtMembers.Columns.Add("Approval Date", typeof(DateTime));

    dgMembers.DataSource = dtMembers;
}
```

"show checked rows" check event:

```
private void cbShowSelected_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbShowSelected.Checked)
        dtMembers.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Print = True";
    else
        dtMembers.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
}
```

the above code works fine when a users ticks various rows and then checks "show checked rows" so all good up to this point. There will be a couple of users who will need to check a large number of rows so, in the interest of usability, I added code so that if they type a membership number in a search textbox, the datagridview is filtered to that membership number, also if a user types a + symbol and there is only one row in the filter view then it will tick that row. I did that using the following code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.Text.Length - 1) != "+")
        {
            dtMembers.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[_RowString] LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            if (dgMembers.DisplayedRowCount(false) == 1)
            {
                dgMembers.Rows[dgMembers.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = true;
                textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That code does successfully check the checkbox in that row, but if I then go and check "Show Checked Rows" that row isn't included in the resulting filtered view. If I manually check a couple of rows and then check one using the + symbol then all the rows I manually check are shown but the one using the + symbol is not. I debugged the code to be sure that the bool is definitely being set to True for that row, and now i'm stumped! any help would  be really appreciated.

Comment: OK, just did some more testing and need to clarify. If I tick a row using the + symbol and then tick "show selected records" it doesn't show the record. If I manually tick another record first and then tick "show selected records" then it shows both records.

Comment: Maybe you need add "==true" to checked?

Comment: Thanks for your comment starko, I gave that a try but it doesn't help. I had a feeling it wouldn't as the exact same filter syntax works when i manually check a cell. In the interest of trying to keep things simple, i've now created a new project that just has a datagridview, a text box (search) and a check box (show checked rows) and stripped the code right back to basics, unfortunately i still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this myself in the end, I believe the problem was that I was setting the DataGridView value rather than the value in the DataTable to which the DataGridView is bound. So now I am using the following code instead which works:

```
BindingManagerBase bm=this.dgMembers.BindingContext[this.dgMembers.DataSource, this.dgMembers.DataMember];
DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)bm.Current).Row;
dr["print"] = true
```